# System Preferences Date & Time Icon

Tags: icon, system-settings, macos, design

This is more of a curiosity question that's been bugging me and I can't find an answer to. With the new MacOS Sierra, if you open the System Preferences, and look at the Date & Time icon used, the it shows the date July 18th, 10:10:30.
In the past, Apple has typically been purposeful about their use of dates in icons, whether it's the day Steve Jobs came back to Apple, or the release of a new product.
**So the question is, why is July 18th used?**
[image: System Preferences]

Comment: That's an interesting question. The very same date is visible in OS X 10.11 El Capitan, too.

How far back goes this date of July 18th / When did it first appear?

Comment: The Power Mac G4 was introduced on 6/18/01 and 10.1, considered the first "public" version of OS X, was demoed during the keynote at Macworld Expo. Also during that keynote, Steve threw a camera at an assistant after it failed to work during a demo of the then-new Image Capture program.